# How can I set the expiration (TTL) for a queue message with the Azure Storage Queue Logic App connector?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-apps, azure-storage-queues

In my logic app, I see no way to set the TTL or the Expiration Date of a queue message.

[image: Azure Put Message In Storage Queue Logic App Action]

[image: Settings for 'Put a message on a queue']

But it's possible from the UI, so I know the API can do it:

[image: Azure portal: updateuser]

I even tried to "hack" the messagettl query string param into the code view:

```
"actions": {
    "Put_a_message_on_a_queue": {
        "inputs": {
            "body": "@{base64(items('For_each'))}",
            "host": {
                "connection": {
                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azurequeues']['connectionId']"
                }
            },
            "method": "post",
            "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent('updateuser')}/messages?messagettl=3600"
        },
        "runAfter": {},
        "type": "ApiConnection"
    }
}
```

But I get an error:

```
{
 "message": "Unable to match incoming request to an operation."
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out by viewing the API call made to the add queue message UI in Azure Portal. It appends a Query String param `messagettl` which is seconds TTL.

So, I viewed the schema [here](https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#) and found that you can pass a `"queries": {...}` object to to the HTTP call to add a message.

### Final code view JSON:

```
"actions": {
    "Put_a_message_on_a_queue": {
        "inputs": {
            "body": "@{base64(items('For_each'))}",
            "host": {
                "connection": {
                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azurequeues']['connectionId']"
                }
            },
            "method": "post",
            "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent('updateuser')}/messages",
            "queries": {
                "messagettl": 3600
            }
        },
        "runAfter": {},
        "type": "ApiConnection"
    }
}
```

Comment: I migrated to logic apps after they deprecated the old scheduler. I forgot about TTL and a bunch of my jobs didn't expire like they should have when the batch processor was down for a weekend. Ugh. At least I don't have to roll my own method/function/action to get an item added to the queue now. Thank you!

Comment: Does setting messagettl = -1 work as is indicated here in this doc? I wasn't able to get that to work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-message. Error: One of the query parameters specified in the request URI is outside the permissible range.  MinimumAllowed 1; MaximumAllowed 604800